# How can I add one stop point to the distance between two cities in the Dijkstra algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra, discrete-mathematics

In a project at school, the teacher gave us 10 cities and their pairwise distances, and asked us to find the minimum distance from Izmir to Van but with the following restriction:

> You start from İzmir visit some of the other 8 cities on the way and reach to Van, where you stay exactly one night in an intermediate city, move to another one next morning and reach there in the same evening. You may come back to the same intermediate city. What is the minimum distance you must travel for such a task (including at least one night-stay)?

He asked us to solve this problem using the Dijkstra algorithm. I wrote the algorithm with Python without adding stops. The code is below:

```
import heapq

# Distance calculation function.
def distance_calculation_for_cities(cities, starting_node):
    distances = {node: float('infinity') for node in cities}
    distances[starting_node] = 0

    hq = [(0, starting_node)]

    while len(hq) > 0:
        current_distance, current_node = heapq.heappop(hq)
        if current_distance > distances[current_node]:
            continue
        for neighbor, weight in cities[current_node].items():
            distance = current_distance + weight
            if distance < distances[neighbor]:
                distances[neighbor] = distance
                heapq.heappush(hq, (distance, neighbor))

    return distances

# Array for our cities.
cities = {
    'Izmir': {'Ankara': 584, 'Antalya': 448, 'Denizli': 234, 'Erzurum':1468, 'Gaziantep':1123, 'Gümüşhane':1354, 'İstanbul':566, 'Izmir':0, 'Van':1750, 'Bayburt':1407},
    'Ankara': {'Ankara': 0, 'Antalya': 542, 'Denizli': 477, 'Erzurum':876, 'Gaziantep':647, 'Gümüşhane':762, 'İstanbul':453, 'Izmir':584, 'Van':1212, 'Bayburt':815},
    'Antalya': {'Ankara': 542, 'Antalya': 0, 'Denizli': 227, 'Erzurum':1244, 'Gaziantep':763, 'Gümüşhane':1172, 'İstanbul':715, 'Izmir':448, 'Van':1447, 'Bayburt':1183},
    'Denizli': {'Ankara': 477, 'Antalya': 227, 'Denizli': 0, 'Erzurum':1336, 'Gaziantep':978, 'Gümüşhane':1248, 'İstanbul':650, 'Izmir':234, 'Van':1605, 'Bayburt':1275},
    'Erzurum': {'Ankara': 876, 'Antalya': 1244, 'Denizli': 1336, 'Erzurum':0, 'Gaziantep':652, 'Gümüşhane':763, 'İstanbul':1098, 'Izmir':1123, 'Van':684, 'Bayburt':125},
    'Gaziantep': {'Ankara': 647, 'Antalya': 763, 'Denizli': 978, 'Erzurum':652, 'Gaziantep':0, 'Gümüşhane':763, 'İstanbul':1098, 'Izmir':1123, 'Van':684, 'Bayburt':730},
    'Gümüşhane': {'Ankara': 762, 'Antalya': 1172, 'Denizli': 1248, 'Erzurum':211, 'Gaziantep':763, 'Gümüşhane':0, 'İstanbul':1086, 'Izmir':1354, 'Van':618, 'Bayburt':86},
    'İstanbul': {'Ankara': 453, 'Antalya': 715, 'Denizli': 650, 'Erzurum':1229, 'Gaziantep':1098, 'Gümüşhane':1086, 'İstanbul':0, 'Izmir':566, 'Van':1636, 'Bayburt':1126},
    'Bayburt': {'Ankara': 815, 'Antalya': 1183, 'Denizli': 1275, 'Erzurum':125, 'Gaziantep':730, 'Gümüşhane':86, 'İstanbul':1126, 'Izmir':1407, 'Van':532, 'Bayburt':0},
    'Van': {'Ankara': 1212, 'Antalya': 1447, 'Denizli': 1605, 'Erzurum':410, 'Gaziantep':684, 'Gümüşhane':618, 'İstanbul':1636, 'Izmir':1750, 'Van':0, 'Bayburt':532},
    
}
```

**Question 1. Minimum distance for Izmir to Van.**

```
print(distance_calculation_for_cities(cities, 'Izmir'))
```

We need to change this code as I mentioned above. Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Find the shortest distance from A to B, then find the shortest distance from B to C. The sum is the shortest distance from A to C with a condition that you have to pass through B. Looks trivial, so probably not what you want. Where is the problem here?

Comment: I also thought about the method you mentioned, but the problem with this method is that Dijkstra's algorithm finds the minimum distance between 10 points using graph theory. The starting point is Izmir, the ending point is Van. There are 8 cities between these two distances and the distances between these cities are also important. In your solution, dividing other cities is a problem.

Comment: Are you saying that the route has to go through every city?

Comment: @iamsahinemir The issue is not with anatolyg's solution. The issue is with the words that you used to describe your problem. We can't offer a better solution than anatolyg's solution, because we don't understand why this solution doesn't satisfy you. Please explain your problem in more explicit words.

Comment: "Assume that you will be given a task where you start from İzmir
visit some of the other 8 cities on the way and reach to Van, 
where you stay exactly one night in an intermediate city, move to 
another one next morning and reach there in the same evening.
You may come back to the same intermediate city. What is the 
minimum distance you must travel for such a task (including at 
least one night-stay)?" This is the question. I'm sorry if I didn't explain it properly.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the starting point is Izmir, you must visit at least one other city before reaching Van.  If this is correct, I would approach the problem in stages. (1) Using DijKstra find the distance from Izmir to Van keeping track of all possible solutions.  (2) Sort the solutions on shortest distance, then (3) cycle through the solutions picking the first one which passes through a secondary city before reaching Van

Comment: I suspect you would get the right answer if you did `del cities['Izmir']['Van']` before running the Dijkstra algorithm. The constraint is essentially that you can't go Izmir->Van in one step.

Comment: *"stay exactly one night in an intermediate city, move to another one next morning and reach there in the same evening"* << To me this suggests that there must be at least ***two*** intermediate cities (one to sleep and one to move to next morning). But it's very awkward wording. I'm afraid understanding the problem is harder than writing an algorithm to solve the problem.

Comment: @Stef that's true, though in my reading of the question, *"at least one night-stay"* took precedence, i.e. the number of intermediate points only needs to be >=1. It's not the clearest!

Comment: @Stef you are right. Even this is y project and I did something, I couldn’t clearly understand. Btw, thank you guys for your effort.